# Based on outer loop decide which inner loops should run more than once

Tags: java, loops

Below is an example e.g. I have 3 nested loops and 4th outer loop and based on that 4th outer loop I want to decide how many times inner loops run (I want inner loops to run either 1 or 50 (x)).

So since the outer loop goes from 0 to 2 I would want it to make the most inner loop go 50 times (x), then both outer loops go once, then on 1 I want the most inner to go again 50 times the second most outer also 50 times and the 3rd most outer 1 time and then last time when i = 2, I want all 3 to go 50 times.

```
int x=50;

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<x; j++){ //go 50 times when i = 2
        for(int k=0; k<x; k++){ //go 50 times when i=1 or 2
            for(int l=0; l<x; l++){//always go 50 times
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Have you learned about the `? :` conditional operator yet?

Comment: Which part of writing the `l` loop, which always go 50 times, is troubling you?

Comment: Just use some `if`-statements. Also you can use those `if`s to manipulate the amount of loops by editing `x` and so on. Should be pretty basic, just help us understand your question better.

Answer (score 2):

The way you exposed your problem make it pretty hard to understand.

Based on what I understood, and the comments from community, this is my contribution in order to help you achieve your goal.

```
int x=50;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    //go 50 times when i = 2, jsut 1 time otherwise
    int maxJ = i == 2 ? x : 1;
    for(int j = 0; j < maxJ; j++ ){
        //go 50 times when i=1 or 2, go 1 time otherwise
        int maxK = i == 1 || i == 2 ? x : 1;
        for(int k = 0; k < maxK; k++){
            //always go 50 times
            for(int l = 0; l < x; l++){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the third parameter of the `for` loop we decide how we will increment our counter. So, we could change our code to something like this:

```
// if i == 2, then increment by one.
// else, increment by x (running one time)
for(int j = 0; j < x; j = i == 2 ? j + 1 : j + x )
```

Comment: While I understand you wish to be helpful, if the question is unclear, you are better off providing a comment and waiting for clarification before answering.

Comment: Your `i` variable is declared in the outer loop, so it's visible for everything inside it.

Comment: Its a problem on the question, not of the answer

Comment: @MiguelKVidal Was that comment supposed to address my comment? Because it doesn't. It doesn't address Joe's comment either, so I don't know what you were trying to clarify with that comment.

Comment: @Andreas sorry... My mistake... Now I understood what you said... As I said in my answer, the question is confuse. But now, based on the OP comment on another question, I believe I understood what he/she wants. I will update my answer

Comment: based on another *answer*, where he said "so the comment [...] means to go 1 time when i is not 2"

Comment: Yeah, I left that comment, and your updated code doesn't do that either. When `i` is not 2, the `j` loop will not iterate at all.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas! Forgot to remove that `i == 2` from the `for`.

Comment: Down-vote removed, but I think that `for (int j = 0; j < (i == 2 ? x : 1); j++)` would be more clear, hence [my original comment to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552917/based-on-outer-loop-decide-which-inner-loops-should-run-more-than-once#comment80060505_46552917) (*Have you learned about the `? :` conditional operator yet?*), before trying to write an answer, or even better, guiding OP into finding solution on their own.

Comment: @Andreas I do understand your concern and thank you for the tips on how to improve not only my answer, but also on how to guide the OP to find the answer by his/her own efforts. I will keep that in mind so I can guide/help before answering from now onwards. Also, I will improve my answer with your snippet, which I agree, but will show how to do it on both ways.

Answer (score 1):

use if just before every loop put an if(i==what ever) x=50 or what ever you want

Answer (score -1):

Is it something like this you need?

```
int x=50;
iloop:for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < x ; j++) 
        {
            if(j>0 && i!=2)
                continue iloop;
        for (int k = 0; k < x ; k++)
            {
            for (int m = 0; m < x ; m++)
                {
                    if(i==0 && m==(x-1))
                        continue iloop;
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too much redundant code. Code should be DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), if possible, and it certainly is. And you forgot what should happen when `i == 0`. When you then write that as an `else` at the end, you'd realize what you might as well get rid of the `i` loop, and simply rearrange the 3 blocks in reverse order. And that would negate the entire point of the question.

Comment: @Andreas tried reducing the redundancy...check one thanks

Comment: `k` loop comment says *"go 50 times when i=1 or 2"*, and `m` loop says *"always go 50 times"*. You're doing neither in the updated answer.

Comment: @Andreas in my case m loop will always go 50 times

Comment: I guess that depends on where you put the logic that should be in the `l` loop. Your way of doing it is convoluted to follow.